# Displaying Wins-Loss-Ties

Tags: java, if-statement, increment

I am creating a Rock, Paper, Scissors game, and I want to have it display the individual wins, losses, and ties.

When I run it, it always says that I lose.

The problem I think is either with the if-then statements that are to increment the right value.

```
if(ret == 1)//starts the increases of wins and losses
           {
               if(ret != 0)
               {
                   if (ret != 2)
                   {
                    w += 1;
                   }
               }
           }

           if(ret == 0)
           {
               if(ret != 1)
               {
                   if(ret != 2)
                   {
                       l += 1;
                   }
               }
           }

           if(ret == 2)
           {
               if(ret != 1)
               {
                   if(ret != 0)
                   {
                       t += 1;
                   }
               }
           }
```

---

Or in this method that determines whether the person won or loss.

```
public static int winnerRet(char user, char compGuess)// method to determine winner
   {
        int ret = 3;
        if(user == 'R')
        {
            if(compGuess != 'P')
            {
                if(compGuess != 'R')
                {
                    ret = 1;
                }
                ret = 2;
            }
            ret = 0;
        }
        if(user == 'S')
        {
            if(compGuess != 'R')
            {
                if(compGuess != 'S')
                {
                    ret = 1;
                }
                ret = 2;
            }
            ret = 0;
        }
        if(user == 'P')
        {
            if(compGuess != 'S')
            {
                if(compGuess != 'P')
                {
                ret = 1;
                }
                ret = 2;
            }
            ret = 0;
        }
        return ret;
   }//end winnerRet
```

---

The last thing I think it could be is the method that generates the computers choice.

```
   public static char compChoice()//starts method to generate computure choice
   {
        Random random = new Random();
        int compNum;
        char compGuess = '\0';
        compNum = 1 + random.nextInt(3);
        if (compNum == 1)
        {
            compGuess = 'R';
        }
        if(compNum == 2)
        {   
            compGuess = 'S';
        }
        if(compNum == 3)
        {
            compGuess = 'P';
        }
        return compGuess;
   }//end method compChoice
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Are there any errors given when you run the program?

Comment: You may want to try combining your if/else statements with logical operators (&& and ||) to make this readable

Comment: A lot of your if statements are redundant. If it equals something, it definitely can't equal the other two.

Comment: Your code is horribly opaque, and you should probably be using enums in multiple places.

Comment: Let's start with `if(ret == 1) { if(ret != 0) { if (ret != 2){ w += 1; } } } `, what is your logic there? 1 is already not 0 or 2....

Comment: What is the use of `int ret = 3;` on line 3? Why not put in `else { int ret = 3; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't a direct answer to your question of "where is the bug", I think your entire solution could be improved.
With that in mind I've used an enumeration for the plays and a simple function that tests all the game rules. I think it is faster to debug/understand this way. See if it helps you:

The ENUM:

```
public enum Play{
    ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS;
}
```

And the Function, that returns false if player1 loses or true if player1 wins:

```
public boolean play(Play player1, Play player2) throws UnsuportedPlayException{
    // rock wins scissors
    if(player1 == Play.ROCK && player2 == Play.SCISSORS)
        return true;
    if(player2 == Play.ROCK && player1 == Play.SCISSORS)
        return false;

    //rock loses to paper
    if(player2 == Play.ROCK && player1 == Play.PAPER)
        return true;
    if(player1 == Play.ROCK && player2 == Play.PAPER)
        return false;

    //paper loses to scissors
    if(player1 == Play.PAPER && player2 == Play.SCISSORS)
        return false;
    if(player2 == Play.PAPER && player1 == Play.SCISSORS)
        return true;
    throw new UnsuportedPlayException("That play is not yet available.");
}
```

The exception was created by me just to handle nulls or if you decide to add plays and forget to add the rules (you might want to add a fourth possible play, just for fun).

The Exception class:

```
public class UnsuportedPlayException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UnsuportedPlayException() {
        super();
    }

    public UnsuportedPlayException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public UnsuportedPlayException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public UnsuportedPlayException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, another quick question, when I tried to implement your suggestion it gives me the error "cannot find symbol - class UnsuportedPlayException". Do you know why that could be happening?

Comment: It is an Exception class. You must create the class with the code I've added after "The Exception class".
You should read a little about exceptions in Java if you are not familiar with them. Here's a start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that last bit. My bad.

Comment: No problem, I added it later. If it solves your problem don't forget to upvote/accept as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in your winnerRet method.
This code:

```
if(user == 'R')
        {
            if(compGuess != 'P')
            {
                if(compGuess != 'R')
                {
                    ret = 1;
                }
                ret = 2;
            }
            ret = 0;
        }
```

will ALWAYS set ret to 0.  If the logic does dive into one of the inner if statements the ret variable still gets set to 0 at the end.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `ret=0` is last statement of if condition so it will always assign ret value to 0

Instead of

```
if(user == 'R'){
            if(compGuess != 'P')
            {
                if(compGuess != 'R')
                {
                    ret = 1;
                }
                ret = 2;
            }
            ret = 0;
}
```

Use below code

```
if (user == 'R') {
            ret = 0;
            if (compGuess != 'P') {
                ret = 2;
                if (compGuess != 'R') {
                    ret = 1;
                }
        }
}
```

Use this type of assignment for other two if condition also.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissor {

    static String ret;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String computer = compChoice();
        winnerRet(args[0], computer);

    }

    public static void winnerRet(String user, String compGuess) {

        if (user.equals("R")) {
            if (!compGuess.equals("P")) {
                if (!compGuess.equals("R")) {
                    ret = "Win";
                } else {
                    ret = "Draw";
                }
            } else {
                ret = "Lose";
            }
        } else if (user.equals("S")) {
            if (!compGuess.equals("R")) {
                if (!compGuess.equals("S")) {
                    ret = "Win";
                } else {
                    ret = "Draw";
                }
            } else {
                ret = "Lose";
            }
        } else if (user.equals("P")) {
            if (!compGuess.equals("S")) {
                if (!compGuess.equals("P")) {
                    ret = "Win";
                } else {
                    ret = "Draw";
                }
            } else {
                ret = "Lose";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(compGuess);
        System.out.println(ret);

    }

    public static String compChoice() {

        String compGuess;

        Random random = new Random();
        int compNum = random.nextInt(3) + 1;

        if (compNum == 1) {
            compGuess = "R";
        } else if (compNum == 2) {
            compGuess = "S";
        } else {
            compGuess = "P";
        }

        return compGuess;

    }

}
```

Well, I quickly built a rock-paper-scissor game without the counting part myself based on your code. It seems to be working. Well, I guess you can look at my code and edit yours based on it. I think the problem was that you were comparing chars with `==`. I used strings, so you can interchange it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Move enum and let it do the work for you. It is much more readable than all the if statements.
Also the reason you need the initMoves is that you can't reference the enums before they are initialized (however they reference each other).

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Move.initMoves();
    Move computerMove = Move.randomMove();
    Move.ROCK.printWin(computerMove);
    Move.PAPER.printWin(computerMove);
    Move.SCISSORS.printWin(computerMove);
  }

  private static enum Move {

    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS;

    private Move beats;

    private Move() {}

    private static void initMoves() {
      ROCK.beats = SCISSORS;
      PAPER.beats = ROCK;
      SCISSORS.beats = PAPER;
    }

    public void printWin(Move computer) {
      if (this == computer) {
        System.out.println("It was a tie.");
      } else if (this.beats == computer) {
        System.out.println("Player wins.");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Computer wins.");
      }
    }

    public static Move randomMove() {
      int move = new Random().nextInt(3);
      switch(move) {
      case 0:
        return ROCK;
      case 1:
        return PAPER;
      default:
        return SCISSORS;
      }
    }
  }
}
```